# Use external mouse with Limbo

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I'm using the Limbo PC Emulator on my Samsung I9305 running rooted stock 4.4.4.

If I plug in an external mouse through USB OTG or (I presume) Bluetooth, there are two cursors on the screen. Limbo's cursor, and the Android cursor. In order to move the Limbo cursor, I have to click and drag with the mouse just as I would have had to using the touch screen.

Is it possible to just have once cursor, that responds directly to the external mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, later versions add a feature that captures external mouse movement and actions and hides the android mouse.